# Python vlookup issue

Tags: python

I'm trying to use `python-vlookup`, with the following script:

```
###
from python_vlookup import python_vlookup
for faster_vlookup
csv_rows = python_vlookup.get_csv_data('example.csv')
column_dict = python_vlookup.create_column_dict(csv_rows,1)
###

lookup_value = 'outdoor/accessories'
lookup_list = ['bed-and-bath/accessories','bed-and-bath/storage-and-hampers/storage','decor-and-pillows/rugs/hide']


print python_vlookup.vlookup(lookup_value,'example.csv',2)
print python_vlookup.vlookup(lookup_list,'example.csv',3)

print python_vlookup.faster_vlookup(lookup_list,column_dict)
```

But I get this error:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'example.csv'

How do I put my file in the directory to resolve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You need to have the `example.csv` in the directory for your program to work. Please update your example code to have proper indenting, as it stands it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Either start using full paths (recommended), such as:

```
csv_rows = python_vlookup.get_csv_data('C:\\Users\\YourUser\\Desktop\\example.csv')
```

Or you can just move the `example.csv` file into your main script directory.
Aka they need to reside in the same folder, for instance on the desktop.

For instance:

```
C:\
 |
 |-- My Folder
         |
         |-- example.csv
         |-- myscript.py
```

1. By opening the **Startmenu** -> then write "cmd" + <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Then write "C:" + <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the black window/console
3. And then write `cd "my folder"`+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Finally, write `C:\Python34\python.exe myscript.py`+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

**Note:** This assumes Python3.4, replace the C:\Python32\ path with wherever you installed Python.

If you're using Linux, you'd probably just need to do:

1. `cd /home/user/my_folder && python myscript.py`

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

try using the full path to the file...

example:
i have a file called `example.csv` in my desktop

if you are using Windows, for example, you should refer to it as:

```
C:\Users\$USER\Desktop\example.csv
```

in Linux it should be:

```
/home/user/Desktop/example.csv
```

so.. try changing the:

```
csv_rows = python_vlookup.get_csv_data('C:\Users\zum77\Desktop\example.csv')
```

IMO, you should create a filepath variable and set the path to the file, so when you need to call it again, just call the variable

```
filepath = "C:\Users\zum77\Desktop\example.csv"

csv_rows = python_vlookup.get_csv_data(filepath)
```